# How to prevent Sunspot, Solr returning all records when params[:search] = ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, railscasts

I just started learning to use Sunspot / Solr with Rails.

I followed this RailsCast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

When I have no search queries and the search field is blank, Solr is returning all results from the Article model by default.

Here's my ArticlesController#index

```
def index
    @search = Article.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @articles = Article.all
    @search_results = @search.results
end
```

When entering no params and just "" in the search bar, the console outputs the following:

```
Started GET "/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-17 12:28:09 -0800
  Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>""}
  SOLR Request (17.0ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f9b5a6643e0> parameters={data: fq=type%3AArticle&start=0&rows=30&q=%2A%3A%2A, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms | Solr: 17.0ms)
[2013-01-17 12:28:09] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

---

The behavior I want is for nothing to be returned unless a search term is given.
I tried modifying the ArticlesController#index as follows:

```
def index
    if params[:search] = ""
      @search_results = []

    else
      @search = Article.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
      end
      @search_results = @search.results

    end
    @articles = Article.all
  end
```

With this condition, when I enter nothing in the search field so that `param[:search] = ""`, nothing is returned from Solr, which is desired behavior.

```
Started GET "/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-18 12:02:52 -0800
  Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>""}
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 14.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
[2013-01-18 12:02:52] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

However, when I enter the search term "ruby" so that `param[:search] = "ruby"`, nothing is returned and Solr isn't being called at all.

```
Started GET "/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=ruby" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-17 12:37:58 -0800
  Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"ruby"}
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 14.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
[2013-01-17 12:37:58] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Is there a problem with my conditional logic? Or, am I missing something about how Solr works? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you making this call: `@articles = Article.all` ?

Comment: I want two instance variables available to Article#index ... `@articles` to show all articles and `@search_results` for the search results when user enters a search term. It's working fine except that `@search_results` is populated even when a search field is blank and `params[:search] = ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solr schema defines a `defaultQuery` to be run when no `q` param is supplied, or its value is an empty string.

Sunspot's `defaultQuery` is `*:*` (the match-all-docs query); furthermore, Sunspot itself more explicitly sends a `*:*` when `fulltext` is supplied with an empty string.

If you don't want a match-all-documents query in this case, you're best off checking the user-supplied query in your controller and skipping the call to Solr entirely.

This is actually exactly what you're doing in your example, so I'm perhaps unclear on the real question. You say, "The behavior I want is for nothing to be returned," and then, describing your conditional, "With this condition, nothing is returned." Seems like you've already solved your own problem?

---

Edit, on clarification:

Unless this is a typo, you probably want to change `if params[:search] = ""` to `if params[:search] == ""`. Note the equality versus assignment operator.

(Or, better still: `params[:search].blank?`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the Solr default schema. My question needed to be clarified. The problem is that after checking the user-supplied query in the controller, it skipped Solr entirely when no param was given as desired ; however, when I tried a param that should return results, the call to Solr was still skipped. Are there any problems in the conditional? Or am I misunderstanding something about Solr? Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks Nick, it was as simple as missing the ==